# Sufficiently escaping HTML and Javascript

Tags: scala, playframework

From the documentation, I believed that `Html(value)` is sufficient escaping for HTML and Javascript. But this code lets HTML tags pass without escaping.

```
<ul>
@*here is the loop*@
@nodes.map{ n =>
<li> @Html( n) </li> }
</ul>
```

Please give the code that will **sufficiently escape** HTML and Javascript (and all other dangerous things) before rendering the view.

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the opposite. the `Html` function outputs the raw string **without** escaping it. By default Play escapes dynamic content that's inserted into the templates. See the [section on Escaping in the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.3/ScalaTemplates).

Comment: So it will escape JS but not HTML? How to escape HTML as well?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What's 'it'? The Html function or the play templating library? You don't have to do anything to escape html (including <script> tags). So, in your example, you should just be able to replace line 4 with `<li> @n </li> }`.